# Select from array in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL to select from a static set of integers? Given an array of integers like 1 and 2, what is the correct syntax in MySQL to do something like:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    (values(1),(2))
```

Which should return one row containing the number 1 and one row containing the number 2.

In other SQL than MySQL (e.g. MSSQL) this is possible. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: would you please elaborate it more ? what is  "  (values(1),(2)) as a" ?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What does `values(1),(2)` represent?

Comment: If you mean select specific attributes, then of course you can. If you mean that one attribute value IS an array, then I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In MSSQL this syntax is possible. 1 and 2 are example numbers of my array.

Comment: No, these are constant values. Suppose, that I want to select from integers.

Comment: I still have no idea what you want. Perhaps show us in the original post some explicit examples of what it is you want to achieve and with what data.

Comment: I want to select from a static set of integers. It does not matter what I want to achieve with that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you mean something like this?

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
```

Comment: No worries. Sorry for being initially so dumb to your question.

Comment: I always forget to add the select. pretty simply but so annoying. thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 14):

The only way to create a virtual set in MySQL is using a subquery with `UNION`. The subquery in the `FROM` clause creates 3 rows which can be joined with another table:

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS num UNION
    SELECT 2 AS num UNION
    SELECT 3 AS num
) virtual
LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.num = virtual.num
```

When you want to use your list of values as a condition for `WHERE` or `ON` clause, then the `IN()` construct may be the right way to go:

```
SELECT foo.* FROM foo WHERE foo.num IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Very helpful, got to give the correct answer to michael, he has helped me to put the right question.

Comment: Guess it's the way to select from a subquery: select id from db1 where url in (select url from db2)

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my english

you can use (IN) like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3....)
```

Comment: this answer is wrong, this is not what they are asking about